# Stackoverflow for stackoverflow Serializing and deserializing classes

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Im getting a stackoverflow when deserilizing a class.

here is the code.

```
public static Object Load(this Object Value)
{
    if (File.Exists(SaveAsFilePath))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer GetOBJ = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Value.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType);
        System.IO.TextReader ReadStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(SaveAsFilePath);

        Object NewValue = GetOBJ.Deserialize(ReadStream);
        ReadStream.Close();
        return NewValue;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using Break is starts here.

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer GetOBJ = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Value.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType);
System.IO.TextReader ReadStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(SaveAsFilePath);

Object NewValue = GetOBJ.Deserialize(ReadStream);
```

and loops at the end back to getting the XMLSerializer.

I can't imagine this is anything to do with the write, that writes out fine and i have a file that shows XML code. however if more code is required please advise.

Comment: You may have a self referencing loop in your XML. Can you post the XML?

Comment: "The exception that is thrown when the execution stack overflows because it contains too many nested method calls." - Probably you have unwanted recursion.